# how to create navbar like gmail tab navbar using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to create a navbar like Gmail Tab Navbar which has Primary,Social,Promotions,Updates. I have to do this using just bootstrap and not use of angular js.Is this possible via just bootstrap?

```
<!-- tabs -->
          <div class="container">
        <div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#twee" data-toggle="tab">Twee</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">Content for Tab 1.Content for Tab 1.Content for Tab 1.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="two">Content for Tab 2.Content for Tab 2.Content for Tab 2.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="twee">Content for Tab 3.Content for Tab 3.Content for Tab 3.</div>
           </div>
        </div>
              </div>
                <div class="container">
        <!-- /tabs -->
```

I need to apply custom background for each tab and when the tab is active, then there will be a straight line at the top of the tab as like gmail. How do i acheive this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It might involve both bootstrap and jquery. Have you tried anything..?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh, yes i have tried a code and i have added in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the standard Bootstrap css/js/jquery and Font Awesome (or any font library).

Its just the standard nav-pills from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) and some CSS to achieve the GMailish look along with making it respond to mobile devices.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
#gmailTab .tab-content {
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
#gmailTab .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#gmailTab .nav-pills > li.active > a,
#gmailTab .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus,
#gmailTab .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
  border-top: 3px solid #f00;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-pills > li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>GMail Menu  </h1>

</div>
<div id="gmailTab" class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"> <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Primary</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Social</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Promotions</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Updates</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#5" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-weixin"></i> Forums</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
      <h3>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years.</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4">
      <h3>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years.</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="5">
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the tabs are not arranging correctly when the screen get shrink and becomes like the mobile size. Can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: How are they supposed to arrange because I don't believe the standard gmail application shows those tabs on the mobile website.

Comment: This is what I need.